# Use MIN() where you cannot GROUP?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I feel pretty dumb, but I get stuck with an apparently very easy query. I have something like this, where every row is a user that watched a movie:

```
user_id     date    duration
   1      01-01-01    62m
   1      03-01-01    95m
   2      02-01-01    58m
   2      06-01-01    25m
   2      08-01-01    95m
   3      03-01-01    96m
```

Now, what I would like to have is a table where I have the first movie watched by each user and its `duration`. The problem is if I use `MIN()` then I have to `GROUP` both `user_id` and `duration`. But if I `GROUP` for `duration` as well, then I am basically going to have the same table back. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does your table have a key? (Does a user watch just one movie a day?)

Comment: Users watch several movies every day. The table has a primary key, which is "session_id".

Comment: do you record the TIME they started watching the movie?

Comment: What do you want the query to show when a user has watched several movies on the latest date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ASC),
         user_id, date, duration
  FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT user_id, date, duration FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

The advantage of `ROW_NUMBER` is that you can change the logic easily. For example, if you want to reverse the logic and get the row of the last watched film per user, you just have to change `ORDER BY date ASC` to `ORDER BY date DESC`.

The advantage of the`CTE` (common-table-expression) is that you can also use it to delete or update these records. Often used to delete or identify duplicates. So you can first select to see what will be deleted/updated before you execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query. I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT date, duration FROM tablename n
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT date, user_id FROM tablename g
        WHERE n.user_id = g.user_id AND g.date < n.date
        );
```

Comment: This is essentially same as @wildplasser's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can only be a single record per user per date, it'd be something like this:

```
select y.*
from table t
inner join (
  select user_id, min(date) mindate
  from table
  group by user_id
) t1
  on  t.user_id = t1.user_id
      and t.date = t1.mindate
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. Every day a single user can watch as many movies as he wants. Therefore the same user can have multiple rows with the same date. The primary key of the table is "session_id".

Comment: @AnnoysParrot This will work even if a user has watched the same movie several times on the last day.  It will then show several rows for that date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` which is a ranking function that generates sequential number for every group based on the column that you want to sort. In this case, if there is a tie, only one record for every user is selected but if you want to select all of them, you need to use `DENSE_RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT  user_id, date, duration
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  user_id, date, duration,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) rn
              FROM tableName
        ) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

this also assumes that the data type of column `date` is `DATE`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first watch_date per user, there should be no date before this date for this user:

```
SELECT *
FROM watched_movies wm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM watched_movies nx
  WHERE nx.user_id = wm.user_id
  AND nx.watch_date < wm.watch_date
  );
```

Note: I replaced the `date` column by `watch_date`, since date is a reserved word (type name).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use windowing functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT user_id, date, duration, MIN(date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS MIN_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
) AS RESULTS
WHERE date = MIN_DATE
```

The over clause and partion by will "group by" the user_id and select the min date per user_id without eliminating any rows.  Then you select from the table where the date is equal to the min date and you are left with the first date per user_id.  This is a common trick once you know about windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the duration of the first movie watched on the earliest date:

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.date, a.duration
FROM table a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,min(date) date FROM table GROUP BY user_id) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND a.date = b.date
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,date,min(session_id) FROM table GROUP BY user_id, date) c ON b.user_id = c.user_id AND b.date = c.date AND a.session_id = c.session_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH TABLE1
    AS (SELECT
             '1' AS USER_ID,
             '01-01-01' AS DT,
             62 AS DURATION
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '1' AS USER_ID,
             '03-01-01' AS DT,
             95 AS DURATION
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '2' AS USER_ID,
             '02-01-01' AS DT,
             58 AS DURATION
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '2' AS USER_ID,
             '06-01-01' AS DT,
             25 AS DURATION
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '2' AS USER_ID,
             '08-01-01' AS DT,
             95 AS DURATION
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             '3' AS USER_ID,
             '03-01-01' AS DT,
             96 AS DURATION
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      *
FROM
      (SELECT
            USER_ID,
            DT,
            DURATION,
            RANK ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID ORDER BY DT ASC) AS ROW_RANK
       FROM
            TABLE1)
WHERE
      ROW_RANK = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query to get the min date then join that back to the table to get all other relevant columns.

```
SELECT  T2.user_id
        ,T2.date
        ,T2.duration
FROM    YourTable T2
INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT  T1.user_id
                ,MIN(T1.date) as first_date
        FROM    YourTable T1
        ) SQ
ON      T2.user_id = sq.user_id
AND     T2.date = sq.first_date
```